# Laravel select * where id =(select id )

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

Using Laravel eloquent how do I make a query like this:

```
 select * from branches where user_id =(select id from users where name ='sara' )
```

Comment: Do you have the relationships set up between branches and users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `user` relationship in your `Branch` model you could use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$branches = Branch::whereHas('user', function ($query) {

    $query->where('name', 'sara');

})->get();
```

---

**Update**

If you're using v8.57.0 or above, you can now use the [whereRelation()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#inline-relationship-existence-queries) method instead:

```
Branch::whereRelation('user', 'name', 'sara')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $id = Users::select('id')->where('name','sara')->first();
 $barnches = branches::where('id',$id)->get();
```

Here Users and branches are models , first is using for 1 row and get for many rows

Answer (score 0):

I would split it into two queries. First getting the id, then getting the list. Expecting your models to be called "User" and "Branches"

```
$user = User::where('name', 'sara');
$id = $user->id;
$branches = Branch::where('id', $id);
```

This site may help you [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```php
$name = 'sara';

$results = BranchModel::whereIn("user_id", function ($query) use ($name) {
    $query->select("id")
        ->from((new UserModel)->getTable())
        ->where("name", $name);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this**:

```
$users = User::whereName("sara")->get()->pluck('id');
Branch::whereIn('user_id',$users)->get();
```